# Have a UIContainerView point to a ViewController in another Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that `UIContainerView` can be used to embed a `UIViewController` inside another `UIViewController` in a Storyboard. However, I would like the embedded `UIViewController` to live in a *different Storyboard file*. Is this possible, and if so, how do I make the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by following the these steps:

1. In the Storyboard that contains the view controller you want to segue to, set the Storyboard ID for that view controller.
2. In the storyboard containing the container view, drag a *Storyboard Reference* from the Object library.
3. From the attribute inspector, set the Storyboard that contains the view controller you want to segue to, and set the Referenced ID to the ID you set in step 1.
4. Connect the embed segue between your container view and the storyboard reference like if it is a view controller in the same storyboard.

That's all!