# Show two view components in one controller but from two files (xib/storyboard)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I would like to implement something like below:

[image]

But, I would like to have my first version app **without** the map, later on, I will add the map. So, the eventual goal is to show both map and the other things showing on above screen.

**My question is,** how to make it happen? It sounds like I should have the map and the rest UI in two files (xib or storyboard) respectively, then later on, combine them together. But I am not sure what is the right way to implement these things in iOS?

Can I implement a view component which only contains map, then, another view component only contains the rest, then later on, combine them & one UIViewController associate with the combined view? If so, how to do it? If not, what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do u need two files ? Now create a xib without a map in future update of the app edit the xib and add map whats the confusion here ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, no confusion with your suggestion at all. But the point of my question is how to do it in separate files. There is nothing wrong I would like to know alternative solutions, right?

Comment: @leem-fin : I agree. I meant u can achieve your goal without creating two files thats all :) But if you are really keen on doing it You can use container view as suggested in answer or simply add two viewController's view as subview to single VC. So as u mentioned u can have two VC one for map and one for rest. For now u can add rest content VC's view as subView covering whole screen later when u have map u can use auto layout constraint and add both VC's view as subview. Container will make ur life easy though :P

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that by using *container views*; add 2 container views to your view controller in your Storyboard, the upper container view will contain the map and its stuff, and the bottom one will contain anything else.

To hide the first container view in your first version of the app you'll only need to set the height constraint of the upper container view to 0 after setting the other constraints properly.

If you wanted to use a view controller from another Storyboard file, you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44990483/4763963).

Comment: Good one :) hence +1

Comment: Thank you @SandeepBhandari!